# Dynamically pass object type to generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I've been playing around with generics, and am trying to figure out how (if possible) I can use a single method across multiple classes by passing the object dynamically.

I have a couple of classes, Foo and Bar as per below:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{
    private string m_Code;
    private Bar m_Bar = new Bar();

    public string Code
    {
        get { return m_Code; }
        set { m_Code = value; }
    }

    public Bar Bar
    {
        get { return m_Bar; }
        set { m_Bar = value; }
    }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable()]
public class Bar
{
    private string m_Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name = value; }
    }
}
```

If I populate my class with some dummy data as such:

```
Foo.Code = "myFoo";
Foo.Bar.Name = "myBar";
```

I have a generic method to return a value from the class:

```
public static object getItem<T>(T obj, string _Value)
{
try
{
    object _Resolved = null;
    _Resolved = obj.GetType().GetProperty(_Value).GetValue(obj, null);
    return _Resolved;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

Calling my getItem method like below works fine.

```
string FooCode = Convert.ToString(getItem<Foo>(myFoo, "Code")) // returns "myFoo"
string BarName = Convert.ToString(getItem<Bar>(myFoo.Bar, "Name")) // returns "myBar"
```

What I am curious about is if there is a generic way of addressing my getItem method, by defining the object?

For example:

```
object myObject = Foo;
string FooCode = Convert.ToString(getItem<typeof(myObject)>(myObject, "Code")) // And this would returns "myFoo"
```

or:

```
object myObject = Bar;
string BarName = Convert.ToString(getItem<typeof(myObject)>(myObject, "Name")) // And this would returns "myBar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getItem` method, you are not using the Type parameter `T`.
For your specific question (where type of `obj` is not known at compile time), you could simply define your method as follows -

```
public static object getItem(object obj, string _Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```
string FooCode = Convert.ToString(getItem(myFoo, "Code")) // returns "myFoo"
string BarName = Convert.ToString(getItem(myFoo.Bar, "Name")) // returns "myBar"
```

It automatically infer type of object. If you want to call Generic method at runtime from object type then you have to create generic method using reflection. Following is the example.

```
public class Program 
{
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo myFoo = new Foo();
            myFoo.Bar = new Bar();
            myFoo.Bar.Name = "Jinal";
            myFoo.Code = "Ths is test";
            // By Using infer
            string FooCode = Convert.ToString(getItem(myFoo, "Code")); // returns "myFoo"
            string BarName = Convert.ToString(getItem(myFoo.Bar, "Name"));

            // Using Reflection
            Type ex = typeof(Program);
            MethodInfo mi = ex.GetMethod("getItem");
            object foo = myFoo;
            var methodgetItem =  mi.MakeGenericMethod(foo.GetType());
            string result = Convert.ToString(methodgetItem.Invoke(null, new object[]{foo , "Code"}));

            object bar = myFoo.Bar;
            var methodgetItem1 = mi.MakeGenericMethod(bar.GetType());
            string result1 = Convert.ToString(methodgetItem1.Invoke(null, new object[] {bar , "Name" }));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static object getItem<T>(T obj, string _Value)
        {
            try
            {
                object _Resolved = null;
                _Resolved = obj.GetType().GetProperty(_Value).GetValue(obj, null);
                return _Resolved;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: The question has declaration of `myFoo` etc as `object`, hence type inference will not help here.. The question specifically talks about the case being a runtime scenario (called dynamic by the OP)